# Can't initiate get request in web.py

Tags: python, web.py

I'm trying to run two servers using web.py and initiating calls from one to another. Both servers start normally but when I try to call a url the below stack trace is thrown.

```
import web

urls = (
    '/ping', 'Ping',
    '/acqlock/+(.*)', 'Acquire',
)

class MSA(web.application):
    def run(self, port=8081, *middleware):
        func = self.wsgifunc(*middleware)
        return web.httpserver.runsimple(func, ('127.0.0.1', port))

app = MSA(urls, globals())
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(port=8081)

class Acquire:
    def GET(self, resource_name):
        print resource_name
        response = app.request('http://127.0.0.1:8080/acqlock/' + resource_name, method='GET')
        return response
```

But I keep getting this error after calling the /acqlock.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\web\wsgiserver\__init__.py", line 1245, in communicate
    req.respond()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\web\wsgiserver\__init__.py", line 775, in respond
    self.server.gateway(self).respond()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\web\wsgiserver\__init__.py", line 2018, in respond
    response = self.req.server.wsgi_app(self.env, self.start_response)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\web\httpserver.py", line 306, in __call__
    return self.app(environ, xstart_response)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\web\httpserver.py", line 274, in __call__
    return self.app(environ, start_response)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\web\application.py", line 279, in wsgi
    result = self.handle_with_processors()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\web\application.py", line 249, in handle_with_processors
    return process(self.processors)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\web\application.py", line 246, in process
    raise self.internalerror()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\web\application.py", line 515, in internalerror
    parent = self.get_parent_app()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\web\application.py", line 500, in get_parent_app
    if self in web.ctx.app_stack:
AttributeError: 'ThreadedDict' object has no attribute 'app_stack'
```

Answer (score 0):

Use requests library for this.

```
  import requests
  response = requests.request(method='GET', url ='http://127.0.0.1:8080/acqlock/' + resource_name)
```

Note: You have used port 8080 in url even though you have hosted the web.py in 8081